# Qt, get ToolTip from button or index

Tags: qt, button, indexing, tooltip, click

I have array of buttons

```
QPushButton* button_download[90];
```

and for each button I set ToolTip

```
button_download[button_download_counter]->setToolTip(get_r.getTrackTitle());
```

and I need to get this ToolTip or button index after click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a slot, you could do something like this:

```
void buttonClicked()
{
    QPushButton *b = qobject_cast<QPushButton *>(sender());
    QString tooltip = b->toolTip();
}
```

Source: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#toolTip-prop